# Sage command line `reset()` fails to create exit command

Tags: sage

I'm using the Sage command line interface, started from a Linux shell. Normally, typing `exit <return>` exits the command line and takes me back to the shell. However, if I use the `reset()` command during a session, this no longer works:

```
[matthew@tera ~]$ /usr/local/sage/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux/sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Sage Version 6.2, Release Date: 2014-05-06                         │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: exit
Exiting Sage (CPU time 0m0.14s, Wall time 0m4.70s).
[matthew@tera ~]$
[matthew@tera ~]$ /usr/local/sage/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux/sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Sage Version 6.2, Release Date: 2014-05-06                         │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: reset()
sage: exit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/sage/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /sage/all_cmdline.py in <module>()
----> 1 exit

NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
sage:
```

Note that `quit` does not work either.

So, it appears that the `reset()` function wipes `exit` from the namespace along with any user variables, and fails to recreate it, as it does `x`, the predefined symbolic variable, for instance.

- Is this a reportable bug, or am I missing something?
- Is there an alternate way to exit the Sage command line? I've gotten stuck in it a few times, and I end up hitting `Ctrl-z` and then ending the shell session; this seems both messy and bad, as I'm causing the shell to kill the Sage process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an alternate way to exit the Sage command line?

I usually use `Ctrl-D` in any case...

But this does indeed appear to be a problem.  Note that this is an Ipython thing, so maybe `reset` is supposed to get rid of the magic things - but I don't see why.  I have opened [Trac 16704](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16704), though it's possible it's desired behavior because it's Ipython.

Comment: Thanks! Does Sage catch `Ctrl-D` just like it catches `Ctrl-C`, or does the OS catch it as it does `Ctrl-z` and send a signal back to Sage? Thanks also for reporting the bug; I wasn't sure how to do that.